# Minimum Number of Sets Needed to Generate the Power Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Take a finite set $A$ with $|A|=n.$ Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the power set of $A$. What is the smallest number of sets needed to generate $\mathscr{F}$? That is, if $\mathscr{C}$ is a set of subsets of $A$, what is the minimum size of $\mathscr{C}$ such that $\sigma (\mathscr{C})=\mathscr{F},$ where $\sigma (\mathscr{C})$ denotes the sigma-field generated by $\mathscr{C}.$

My approach to this is to look at $\mathscr{C}$ being able to generate all the singletons of $A$. So we have an upper bound on the size of $\mathscr{C}$ at $n$, this comes from just letting $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of singletons.

However, looking at the example of $A=\{ 1,2,3\},$ I can get a set that $\mathscr{C}=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$ generates $\mathscr{F}$. So I know that $n$ is not the minimal size, but I am unsure how to go about finding the minimal size.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your same example gives $|C| = 2$ when $n=4$; remember you are allowed to take complements.

Answer (score 4):

The minimal such size is $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$.

To see this, we'll first show that if $|\mathscr{C}| < \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$, then $\mathscr{C}$ cannot generate $\mathscr{F}$. This follows from the fact that $2^{|\mathscr{C}|} < n$, so two elements of $A$ must appear in exactly the same sets of $\mathscr{C}$, so they will appear in exactly the same sets in $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$. However, there exist sets in $\mathscr{F}$ which contain one of these two elements but not the other, hence leading to a contradiction.

On the other hand, we'll show that there is a $\mathscr{C}$ with $|\mathscr{C}| = \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ that suffices. Let $S_i$ be the subset of $\{0, 1, \dots, n-1\}$ consisting of those elements whose $i$th bit (from the right) equals $1$ (when written in binary), and let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of $S_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$. Now, to construct any singleton $\{i\}$, let $X$ equal the set of positions $j$ such that the $j$th bit of $i$ is $1$, and let $Y$ equal the set of positions $j$ such that the $j$th bit of $i$ is $0$. It then follows that

$$\{i\} = \bigcap_{j\in X} S_j \cap \bigcap_{j \in Y} \overline{S_j}$$

and hence this set generates $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When you say that two elements of $A$ must appear in exactly the same sets of $\mathscr{C}$, do you mean that  there are two elements of $A$, $a$ and $b$, so that $a$ and $b$ only appear in the same elements of $\mathscr{C}$? If so, how do we know this is true?

Comment: @User112358 For every element $a\in A,$ put it in $\textit{a subset X of C},$ which is a set of subsets of $A,$ such that, exactly the sets in X contain $a.$ Then by pigeonhole principle, there are two elements of $A$ that are put in the same X, which means that they are contained in the same sets of $C.$ The $\sigma$ does not affect this property then.

Comment: @awllower In forming $\mathscr{C}$ there is nothing that says every element of $A$ must be in a subset in $\mathscr{C}$. Also if the two elements are not only in the same subsets then set operations does affect that property.

Comment: Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements of $A$. Then the property "$a$ and $b$ only appear in the same elements of $C$" is preserved by the operations of sigma-algebras; namely intersection, union, and complementation.

Comment: @jschnei I understand this, what I do not understand is how you justify that there are two such elements of $A$ if $|\mathscr{C}|<\lceil \log_2 (n)\rceil$. For $m<\lceil \log_2 (n)\rceil$ couldn't you just take $\mathscr{C}$ to be $m$ singletons then there are no two elements of $A$ in all the same elements of $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: In that case, take two elements $a$ and $b$ that don't appear in any  of the sets in $C$. These elements only appear in the same elements of $C$ (i.e., none of them).

Comment: In particular the formal condition is: for every pair of elements $a, b$ with $a\neq b$, there exists a set $S \in \mathcal{C}$ such that either $a\in S$ and $b \not\in S$ or $a\not \in S$ and $b \in S$.

Comment: @jschnei In the second half of your answer, where you write the example where $|\mathscr{C}|=\lceil \log_2 (n) \rceil$ and $\mathscr{C}$ generates $\mathscr{F}$ I don't know what much of your notation means. What is $[n]$? What does $i$th bit from the right mean?

Comment: $[n]$ is simply shorthand for $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ (although it turns out it's actually more convenient to work with $\{0, 1, \dots, n-1\}$; I'll edit the answer). The $i$th bit from the right is simply the $i$th bit from the right when written in binary; for example, the 2nd bit from the right in $13 = 1101_2$ is $0$.