# Find subsets A,B,C of the set $X= \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$

Tags: measure-theory

Find subsets A,B,C of the set 
$X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which satisfies that
$\sigma(\{A,B,C\})=P(X)$
where $P(x)$ is the power set. We know that 
$\sigma(\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\})=P(X)$.

We wanna show that $\sigma(\{A,B,C\})=\sigma(\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\})$. So we are gonna show that $\{A,B,C\} \subseteq \sigma(\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\})$ and that $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\} \subseteq \sigma(\{A,B,C\})$.

I know how to show  $\{A,B,C\} \subseteq \sigma(\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\})$, but im not shure how to show $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}\} \subseteq \sigma(\{A,B,C\})$. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\sigma$?

Comment: It is a sigma-algebra

Comment: See also this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426122/minimum-number-of-sets-needed-to-generate-the-power-set?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Take $$A=\{1,4,6\}$$ $$B=\{2,1,5\}$$ $$C=\{2,3,4\}$$

If you do some set theoretic calculations you will see that unions,intersections and set differences of these sets generate all the singletons,so $\sigma(A,B,C)$ contains all the singletons.

Comment: That was also mine idea, but my instructor said that 6, should not be in the subset, because it will not go right.

Comment: I know that the subset should something like $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{3,4,5\}, C=\{1,4,5\}$

Comment: All the set theoretic operation generate all the singletons and since $\sigma(A,B,C)$ is a sigma algebra,then it is closed under all these operations,so it must contain alla the singletons...you can verify it your self.

Comment: Note that if $A,B$  are in a sigma algebra,then A\B is also..this helps a lot to derive what you want.